# Sitecore - Server Error Accessing Content Items (Yellow Screen of Death)

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

Another goofy one... trying to access existing content items originally created by an admin as a regular user but getting the following juicy exception.  I can see the items in the content tree as this user, but the exception is thrown when I click on an item to view it (and presumably to edit it as the next step).

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Null ids are not allowed. Parameter name: displayName
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Null ids are not
>   allowed. Parameter name: displayName
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Null ids are not allowed. Parameter name:
>   displayName]
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument,
>   String argumentName) +75
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFormatter.RenderSectionBegin(Control
>   parent, String controlId, String sectionName, String displayName,
>   String icon, Boolean isCollapsed, Boolean renderFields) +69
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderSectionPanel(XmlNode
>   element) +214
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderElement(XmlNode
>   element) +487
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.AddText(XmlNode
>   element) +423
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderElement(XmlNode
>   element) +533
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.AddText(XmlNode
>   element) +423
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.RenderElement(XmlNode
>   element) +533
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.Render(XmlDocument
>   skin) +93
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor.RenderSkinedContentEditor.Process(RenderContentEditorArgs
>   args) +353    (Object , Object[] ) +61
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters) +36
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.Invoke(Object[] parameters) +43
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +133
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +154
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args, String pipelineDomain) +64
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args) +50
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.Render(RenderContentEditorArgs
>   args, Control parent) +450
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.Render(Item item,
>   Item root, Hashtable fieldInfo, Control parent, Boolean showEditor)
>   +239    Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.RenderEditor(Item
>   item, Item root, Control parent, Boolean showEditor) +153
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateEditor(Item
>   folder, Item root, Boolean showEditor) +238
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update()
>   +249    Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs
>   e) +116
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method,
>   Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +69
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +306
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +22    System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +19
>   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj) +38
>   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Type type, Object obj,
>   String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited,
>   Boolean includeStatic, Object[] parameters) +104
>   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Type type, Object obj,
>   String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited,
>   Object[] parameters) +26
>   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Object obj, String
>   methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited,
>   Object[] parameters) +41
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs
>   e) +87    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +150
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2838
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Comment: Can you see the item when you log in as the admin user?

Comment: @CraigTaylor - When I log in as the admin, I can definitely see the item, but I can see it in the tree as the editor account too.  Oh, I'll add this up top too, but I get the error when I click on the item to edit it.

Comment: Next time you get this error. Clear your cache and refresh the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I went back and removed any custom access rights set on the account (which resolved my issue) after finding the following answer:

> A message that’s very long, but also not very helpful in finding a
>   solution.
>
> The only helpful thing I found was
>   http://egointeractive.posterous.com/argumentnullexception-null-ids-are-not-allowe
>
> **Which mentions the same thing happening because of denied read rights
>   on templates.**
>
> **That did fix the problem**, giving me another one – some fields on some
>   templates shouldn’t be visible for specific users. Luckily the answer
>   to that one was an easy one: All I needed to do was deny the Field
>   Read right, rather than the Read right.

Reference: 
http://trayek.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/sitecore-content-editor-woes/

For posterity, here is the posterous (RIP) link in it's entirety:

> [ArgumentNullException]: Null ids are not allowed. Parameter name:
>   displayName I ran into this error after setting up a user with limited
>   read/write permissions. I created a custom role, assigned 'Sitecore
>   Client Author' and 'Sitecore Client User', assigned the user to the
>   role, and checked that they could log in and see the content tree.
>   Everything seemed fine, until I tried clicking on any of the items
>   under 'Home'. On some occasions, one of two things happened: I got
>   this error: [ArgumentNullException]: Null ids are not allowed.
>   Parameter name: displayName Items that I knew ought to have fields,
>   didn't I tried different combinations of roles (including dropping my
>   custom role and using Sitecore's defaults only), but I still ran into
>   problems - again, only on certain items. As far as I could tell,
>   administrators were the only users able to see items, and there were
>   no examples of working users without admin rights.
>
> The website had recently been upgraded from Sitecore 5 (I'm not sure
>   which version) to Sitecore 6.3.1 (rev. 110112), and as far as I know,
>   it wasn't until after this point that the problem became apparent.
>   I've seen the error before in almost exactly the same circumstances,
>   so I would wager that it has something to do with the upgrade.
>
> When I looked through the permissions for user-created templates (not
>   system templates) permissions, I noticed that inheritance had been
>   denied on section/field child items for quite a few templates. I
>   couldn't see a reason why this should be the case, so I spent some
>   time getting rid of the explicit deny (there were 50+ cases of it in
>   this particular install) - hey presto, the error disappeared! I had to
>   use the 'Remove Inherit' button in the Security Editor ribbon; using
>   'Assign' or unchecking the [ X ] next to the in 'Inheritance'
>   permission for the item didn't work.

Reference: http://web.archive.org/web/20130317212504/http://egointeractive.posterous.com/argumentnullexception-null-ids-are-not-allowe

Comment: Nice to see it helped someone out :-)

Comment: posterous.com seems to have died the great internet death. Wayback machine link: http://web.archive.org/web/20130317212504/http://egointeractive.posterous.com/argumentnullexception-null-ids-are-not-allowe